# How to pass column fields of ng-grid dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-grid of AngularJS, below is the code in my directive:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                data : 'sample',
                columnDefs : [ {
                    field : "username",
                    displayName : "USER NAME",
                    width : 145
                }, {
                    field : "password",
                    displayName : "Password",
                    width : 145
                }],
```

instead of hard coding the display names of the grid I want to display them dynamically from the controller. I am storing the result in a variable in the controller so I want to pass this variable back to the directive and display the column names from the result variable.I can able to pass the values from directive to controller using rootScope so is there any way to pass a value back to directive from controller. 
Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the ColDefs[] from the underlying datasource which caters data for binding

> $scope.griddata = response.data // this is where the data is getting assigned 
>   $scope.gridoptions = { 
>                       data : griddata, 
>                       columnDefs : coldef, // coldef we would build from datasource object 
>                       . 
>                       . 
>                        }

From $scope.gridata, we would extract all the column info like this and assign it to $scope.coldef which is bound to columndefinition

> var fieldnames = Object.key($scope.griddata[0]); //getting column def from json data 
>   for (var i = 0; i < fieldnames.length; i++) { 
>                  $scope.coldef.push({ field: fieldnames[i] }); 
>             }

Now the ColDef are dynamics and build based on the datasource assigned